# Covariance matrix of a set of spherical coordinates

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

How do I compute the covariance matrix of a set of spherical coordinates? I know that I can compute the mean of a set of spherical coordinates by transforming them to cartesian coordinates, compute the mean and then convert the mean value back to spherical. But how can I compute the covariance matrix correctly?